# How can I query the version of the node running a stake pool?

Tags: node

The version of the node running on the entire blockchain can be consulted in [PoolTool](https://pooltool.io/networkhealth).
I want to check the individual version of a stake pool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe PoolTool asks node operators to send them the data.

In bitcoin style nodes there is an RPC `getpeerinfo` and that shows peer info like major version, I dont think there is anything for cardano-node yet.

You could try looking thorough cardano-node logs and see if there is version data exchanged (I expect there is), you would then just need to manually configure `mainnet-topology.json` to point your node to the pool node.

Bear in mind this will only give the public relay version, not the block producer version.